# What is HotSpot?

Tags: java, terminology

I just heard of the HotSpot JVM, as opposed to the Oracle JRockik JVM.  What is Hotspot?  Is this old the Sun JVM, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HotSpot is the shipped Sun JVM which has support for just-in-time compilation of heavily used sections of code.

For all practical purposes, it is the "Sun JVM" or now the "Oracle JVM".  Note that this is the same JVM which was open sourced, so it is also the "OpenJDK JVM".

Way back when, Sun did release a non-JIT capable JVM, but that's long enough ago that the odds of encountering it are minuscule.

Comment: @Daniel, sort of off-topic, but JRocket makes a big deal about it's deterministic garbage collection.  While that's a good thing for reducing unpredictable latency, it doesn't necessarily mean higher performance.  Also, HotSpot can use the new G1 (garbage first) garbage collector, which is far more predictable (and scales better to more cores).  With G1 turned on, I don't know how HotSpot stands against JRocket (but I'd bet it's comparable).

Comment: @Daniel, these flags `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC` might turn on G1 in HotSpot, providing you have a build that supports it.  In HotSpot (version 7) it was rumored to be on by default.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, its the old Sun JVM which is now part of [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/) and therefor a reference for many other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's JVM is called [HotSpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot).

Answer (score 0):

Java applications are compiled into bytecode using `javac`. During application runtime, the JVM loads class files into memory and analyzes the program’s performance for [hot spots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_spot_(computer_programming)); hence the name “[HotSpot JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot)”. The just-in-time (JIT) compiler compiles parts of the application which are executed repeatedly into native machine code. [JIT compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/Oracle-JVM-JIT.html#GUID-23D5BA60-A2B3-45F9-93DF-81A3D971CA50), however, requires processor time and memory which affects the startup time of the application.

[source to my answer](https://blog.indrek.io/articles/running-spring-boot-apps-as-graalvm-native-images/)